# Cannot delete or update parent row JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

JPA doesn't allow me to delete data from gallery table unless I don't clean image table. Anyone have idea how to delete data when I have foreign key?

```sql
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gallery` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SITE_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `DATE_CREATED` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `DATE_DELETED` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_UPDATED` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `TITLE_ENG` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `TITLE_GEO` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `TITLE_RUS` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_9smi5asvs3daquvhnydgar892` (`SITE_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PATH` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `SITE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GALLERY_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_ewyghuij49l5wp3pnxnbg41en` (`GALLERY_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

```sql
ALTER TABLE `images`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_ewyghuij49l5wp3pnxnbg41en` FOREIGN KEY (`GALLERY_ID`) REFERENCES `gallery` (`id`);
```

When i try to delete it shows me Error in log

```
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pp`.`images`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ewyghuij49l5wp3pnxnbg41en` FOREIGN KEY (`GALLERY_ID`) REFERENCES `gallery` (`id`))
```

Comment: There is some record referencing the row you are about to delete, via a foreign key constraint. Deleting the row would violate this constraint. Delete the referencing records first, or delete `CASCADE`.

Comment: Once  Added CascadeType.Remove to field in model, now i can remove gallery reference if its not referenced by some other table